# A famous dodecagon

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, geometry

A 12-sided polygon (Dodecagon) has the property, that neighbouring sides appear 4 times in a ratio of 1:1 and 8 times in a ratio of 7:6. 
Where can such a Dodecagon be found?

Comment: how are you counting "times", there are 66 ways to compare sides.

Comment: The cross has 12 sides and you have 12 neighbouring sides.
The arms of the cross are one sixth longer than their width.
When you start with the top side and go clockwise, you get the ratios
1:1, 7:6, 7:6, 7:6, 7:6, 1:1, 1:1, 7:6, 7:6, 7:6, 7:6, 1:1.
This is what I meant by 4 times in a ratio of 1:1 and 8 times in a ratio of 7:6.
I hope that explains it.

Comment: oh neighbouring, 12 _pairs_ of neighboring sideds, I  missed that.   but I  get 6:7 1:1 7:6 repeated

Comment: correct, if you want to keep the order you get 6:7 and 7:6, but for simplicity I always considered the ratio of the longer side divided by the shorter side.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That would be

> the [flag of Switzerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Switzerland).